# Is there a browser for Win that can be used to test html5 localstorage?

Tags: windows, html, testing, local-storage

I am testing someone else's web application, and the application relies on iphone / android html5 localstorage. I have tried Opera Mobile Emulator, Chrome 12.07, Firefox 5.01, Opera 11.5, Safari 5.1, Safari 5.1 with the iPhone UA, and IE 9.08. As far as I can tell, none of them support localstorage. Is there a mode on one of these browsers that I need to enable to test an application that relies on localstorage in windows? Is there another browser I have not thought of that might have localstorage support?

Comment: All of those browsers support local storage. I can only assume, therefore, that the web app you're testing either doesn't actually use local storage or is using some detection to only operate on mobile devices.

Comment: Thanks for the info! IMHO you should have submitted the comment as an answer ...

Comment: IE has supported it at least since version 8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of those browsers [support local storage](http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage). I can only assume, therefore, that the web app you're testing either doesn't actually use local storage or is using some detection to only operate on mobile devices.

A couple of options:

- Try a user agent switcher ([Firefox has an add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/), Chrome probably does too, Opera has it built in) and set your browser user agent string to mobile Safari or similar
- Download the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), that'll let you emulate an Android device on your desktop